# Workspace url for machine learning experiment notebook

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks

I am running a machine learning experiment in Databricks and I want to obtain the workspace URL for certain uses.

I know how to manually obtain the workspace URL of notebook from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workspace/per-workspace-urls

Similar to how you can obtain the path of your notebook by

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()
```

How do I programmatically obtain the notebook's URL?

Comment: What does *automatedly* mean? I don't believe that *automatedly* is actually a word in the English language. Do you mean *programmatically*, as in *using code*? If not, please be more clear about what you're asking.

Comment: ___Automatedly___ is a word in English, but yes ___programmatically___ is another way to describe what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things available:

- Browser host name - it gives you just host name, without http/https schema, but it's really a name that you see in the browser:

```py
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext() \
  .browserHostName().get()
```

- API URL: base URL with HTTPS schema that you can use to call APIs:

```py
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext() \
  .apiUrl().get()
```

P.S. I really prefer to convert that information into a Python dict that it's easier to investigate and use. I use code like this:

```py
import json
ctx = json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook() \
  .getContext().toJson())
ctx
```

Comment: The python dict for all relevant information on the notebook is very relevant and answers all questions on it's attributes.